# Multithreading with boost QT and mingw

Tags: c++, qt, boost, mingw, boost-bind

I am developping a GUI using C++ (librairie OpenCV) on QT that works fine.
 now i am trying to multithread the code using boost
my method is :

```
//creating thread group
 thread_group mythread;
//then creating threads 

    mythread.create_thread(bind(&MainWindow::setbarvalue,this,0) ) ;

//set max and min of a progressbar to zero to get a floatting progressbar


 mythread.create_thread(bind(&AVI2Image::Convert_AVItoImage,&avitoim,Nom,firstframe, lastframe,Nom_save,digitsnumber)) ;
```

AVI2Image :the class

Convert_AVItoImage: the function

avitoim: instance of the class

then the attributes

this line work either .

the problem begin with this line :

```
 mythread.create_thread(bind(&Lecture_containerYUV::container_YUV2yuv,&lectcont, Nom,Nom_save, width ,height,Redimonsionne,width_desir,height_desir, filter,inputsampling,
                             inputbitdepth,nbimages,digitsnumber,ry6,ru6,rv6,gy6,gu6,gv6,by6,bu6,bv6,coeff1,coeff2,coeff3,contrast,gamma,ry7,ru7,rv7,gy7,gu7,gv7,by7,bu7
                             ,bv7,ry2,ru2,rv2,gy2,gu2,gv2,by2,bu2,bv2));
```

its the same method as above but here I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Mido\Documents\Container_ConverterV_2.4\mainwindow.cpp:363: erreur : no matching function for call to 'bind(void (Lecture_containerYUV::*)(std::string, std::string, int, int, bool, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double, double), Lecture_containerYUV*, std::string&, std::string&, int&, int&, bool&, int&, int&, int&, int&, int&, int&, int&, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&, double&)'
```

and:

```
lectcont.container_YUV2yuv( Nom,Nom_save, width ,height,Redimonsionne,width_desir,height_desir, filter,inputsampling,
                             inputbitdepth,nbimages,digitsnumber,ry6,ru6,rv6,gy6,gu6,gv6,by6,bu6,bv6,coeff1,coeff2,coeff3,contrast,gamma,ry7,ru7,rv7,gy7,gu7,gv7,by7,bu7
                             ,bv7,ry2,ru2,rv2,gy2,gu2,gv2,by2,bu2,bv2);
```

**works fine!!!**

mingw cant find the function i dont understand why !

any help please

Comment: I guess `container_YUV2yuv` is overloaded, isn't it? If so, `bind` can't select the right version automatically, you have to type-cast `container_YUV2yuv` to the appropriate signature explicitly.

Comment: thanks for your comment ,No its not overloaded! its resolved when i add to the .pro file -c++0x :)

Comment: So you actually attempt to call `std::bind`? Obviously, it's available in c++11 only. I was under impression that you mean `boost::bind`.

Comment: There is no any "default" in C++. There're quite complicated function name look-up rules: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/030.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think issue is that you cant enter so match parameters.
I propose that you use the Multithreading of C++11

### MyThread.h

```
#ifndef MyTHREAD_HPP
#define MyTHREAD_HPP

#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

class MyThread {


public:
    MyThread();
    void PrintOutMessage(string msg);
    void PrintOut(int i, int j, int k);
    void PrintOut(int i, int j);
    ~MyThread();
};
#endif
```

### MyThread.cpp

```
#include "MyThread.hpp"


mutex _mu, _mu2;

MyThread::MyThread()
{

}


MyThread::~MyThread()
{
}

void MyThread::PrintOutMessage(string msg)
{

    for (int l = 0; l < 10; l++)
    {

        lock(_mu, _mu2);
        lock_guard<mutex>locker(_mu2, adopt_lock);
        lock_guard<mutex>locker2(_mu, adopt_lock);

        cout<< "message:" << msg << endl;
        Sleep(200);
    }

}

void MyThread::PrintOut(int i,int j,int k)
{


    for (int l = 0; l < 10; l++)
    {
        lock(_mu, _mu2);
        //lock_guard<mutex>locker(_mu2, adopt_lock);
        //lock_guard<mutex>locker2(_mu, adopt_lock);
        unique_lock<mutex>locker(_mu2, adopt_lock);
        unique_lock<mutex>locker2(_mu, adopt_lock);
        cout << "message:" << i << ", " << j << ", " << k << endl;
        Sleep(200);
    }

}

void MyThread::PrintOut(int i, int j)
{


    for (int l = 0; l < 10; l++)
    {
        lock(_mu, _mu2);
        lock_guard<mutex>locker(_mu2, adopt_lock);
        lock_guard<mutex>locker2(_mu, adopt_lock);

        cout << "message:" << i << ", " << j << endl;
        Sleep(200);
    }

}
```

### main.cpp

```
#include "MyThread.hpp"

void (MyThread::*memfunc)(int,int) = &MyThread::PrintOut;
void (MyThread::*memfunc2)(int, int,int) = &MyThread::PrintOut;

void PrintOutmainfunc(int i, int j, int k)
{


    for (int l = 0; l < 10; l++)
    {

        cout << "message:" << i << ", " << j << ", " << k << endl;
        Sleep(200);
    }

}
int main (){

    string msg = " hello world";
    int i = 10, j = 20, k = 30;
    //  string str = lexical_cast<string>(i);
    //cout << "str: " << str << endl;

    MyThread mythread;

    thread t1(memfunc, mythread, i, j);
    thread t2(memfunc2, mythread, i, j, k);
    thread t3(&MyThread::PrintOutMessage, mythread, msg);
    //thread t4(PrintOutmainfunc, i, j, k);

    //thread t3(bind(&MyThread::PrintOutMessage, mythread, msg));

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    //t4.join();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

in this example I putted all possible options for Multithreading